# Chrome 90 printing broken?

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Since upgrading to Chrome 90, I cannot print. Chrome version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (x86_64) on macOS 10.14.6 (18G7016).

- If the page contains an iframe, the print preview dialogue closes and the page reloads. It's impossible to do anything here, even print to PDF is broken.
- The only 'printer' available is 'Save as PDF'
- When I say 'See more' under the Destination, it tries to list cloud print printers. I have none, I have never had any, AND it's deprecated anyway! 10.14.6 (18G7016)
- Clicking on 'Manage' opens the Printers & Scanners where my printer IS listed. It works in everything else.
- Cancelling the print dialogue reload the page without re-posting the same form data.

Printing from Incognito mode doesn't work.
Creating a new Chrome profile and printing from there doesn't work.
Printing on the same network to the same printer from Catalina under the same Chrome version works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you contacted Chrome Support or forums?

Comment: Yes, but asking there is like shouting into a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>Cmd-Shift-P</kbd> to print using system dialog.

---

I have the same issue on Linux and have raised a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1209175). I have also confirmed where the regression occurred in the revision history. The change log talks about reworking the way the Printer list is populated in the Print Preview dialog.